# Combining SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of two neighbour countries

Tags: r, spatial, raster, shapefile

I want to combine the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` of two neighbour countries like Pakistan and India. My MWE is below:

```
library(raster)
Pakistan.adm1.spdf <- 
  getData(
    "GADM"
    , country = "Pakistan"
    , level = 1
  )

India.adm1.spdf <- 
  getData(
    "GADM"
    , country = "India"
    , level = 1
  )
```

How can I combine these two shapefiles?

Comment: Note aside: they are not shapefiles but "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame". They are provided in .RData format.

Comment: Try `rbind(Pakistan.adm1.spdf, India.adm1.spdf, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)`. [source](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32732/proper-way-to-rbind-spatialpolygonsdataframes-with-identical-polygon-ids)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/149907/32309) to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32732/proper-way-to-rbind-spatialpolygonsdataframes-with-identical-polygon-ids), use `rbind` and the argument `makeUniqueIDs`.

```
adm1.spdf <- rbind(Pakistan.adm1.spdf, India.adm1.spdf, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)
plot(adm1.spdf)
```

[image]