# Import multiple shapefiles with different sets of attributes in R and combine them

Tags: r, rgdal, ogr

I have a folder containing many shapefiles that are somehow related but contain different numbers of attributes in the corresponding database (dbf-File).
I managed to load them all into R using

```
files<-list.files(path=".",pattern=".shp$")
files<-sub(".shp","",files)
for(i in files){
  assign(i,readOGR(".",i))
}
```

Now the problem is that the corresponding information are different, sometimes containing a column called "legend" and sometimes not.

```
> str(A@data)
'data.frame':   1704 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ NRKART    : int  6 1 7 15 7 15 1 7 999 999 ...
 $ SCHRAFFUR : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","L": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ TKLE_NR   : int  151806 151801 151807 151815 151807 151815 151801 151807 151800 151800 ...
 $ Symbol    : Factor w/ 86 levels "1","10","100",..: 61 1 62 22 62 22 1 62 54 54 ...
 $ BGL       : Factor w/ 11 levels "0.0","1.1","1.2",..: 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Shape_Area: num  4123982 20460030 436214 3904785 364182 ...
 $ Shape_Len : num  65111 43803 3152 19753 3174 ...

> str(B@data)
    'data.frame':   2705 obs. of  8 variables:
     $ NRKART    : int  22 14 48 42 27 14 14 1 999 48 ...
     $ SCHRAFFUR : Factor w/ 1 level "A": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
     $ TKLE_NR   : int  471822 471814 471848 471842 471827 471814 471814 471801 471800 471848 ...
     $ BGL       : Factor w/ 15 levels "0.0","10.1","11.1",..: 11 11 13 12 12 11 11 6 1 13 ...
     $ SYMBOL_NR : Factor w/ 80 levels "107","161","176",..: 1 24 18 56 67 24 24 36 22 18 ...
     $ Legende   : Factor w/ 84 levels "00 Gewässerflächen",..: 23 15 49 43 28 15 15 2 1 49 ...
     $ Shape_Area: num  2300557 568922 2512166 1044624 13708524 ...
     $ Shape_Len : num  13251 3298 7387 5235 40118 ...
```

My prefered way of merging the two would be to use

```
library(taRifx.geo)
New<-rbind(A,B,fix.duplicated.IDs=TRUE)
```

How do I import or rename each attributed dataframe so it contains all the columns of shape `B`. The name of column Symbol (A) needs to be changed in SYMBOL_NR ,too

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to append the files together, not merge them (you are trying to have the rows of A followed by the rows of B, not trying to combine information from A and B into a single row).

For that, I'd suggest `bind_rows` from `dplyr` (you can use `rename` to fix the column while you are at it). It should match up column names as needed, and fill in the `NA`'s where appropriate.

```
New <-
  bind_rows(
    A@data %>%
      rename(SYMBOL_NR = Symbol)
    , B@data
  )
```

Comment: Your suggestion works for data.frames but I work with shapefiles containing both a dataframe and geographical data. Therefore your solution does not quite work.

Comment: I don't work with shapefiles, so I apologize for the confusion. I didn't realize that `rbind` had a method for handling the additional portions of the shape file. Alternatively, if the geographical data is identical in the two sets, could you assign the `@data` accessor with the `New` data.frame? Or, do a similar `bind_rows` for the other parts of the shapefile?

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108927/combining-spatialpolygonsdataframe-of-two-neighbour-countries)

, and assuming that the comment by @Mark Peterson is doing what you need with the data, this could do what you ask ( if I got the question right):

```
newpolys <- rbind(A, B, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE) 
newdata  <- bind_rows(A@data %>%
                   rename(SYMBOL_NR = Symbol)
                  , B@data
newpolys@data = newdata
```